# How can i extract a text from a string?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "GET";
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    int start = content.IndexOf("profile/");
    int end = content.IndexOf("'");
    string result = content.Substring(start, end - start - 1);
    reader.Close();
    response.Close();
}
```

For example i have a long line:

```
<span class="message-profile-name" ><a  href='/profile/daniel'>daniel</a></span>: <span class="message-text">hello everyone<wbr/> <img class='emoticon emoticon-tongue' src='/t.gif'/></span>
```

I want to build a new string with: daniel hello everyone

How can i do it ?
In my code it dosent work im getting error exception say

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException Length cannot be less than zero. Parameter
>   name: length

On the line: `string result = content.Substring(start, end - start - 1);`
In this case: `start = 19572 end = 2110`

Comment: you should use HTMLAgilityPack to parse and extract content from HTML, doing it by hands is more time consuming and surely more error prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the string you want will always be enclosed inside an href with the format **profile/xxx**, it'd be simple with regex once you get the content into text form, and using regex would still work even if you can have the potential of having multiple *<a href=...>* elements

```
Match match = Regex.Match(content, @"(?<=<a\s*?href='/profile/\w*?'>\s*?)\w*?(?=\s*?<\s*?/a\s*?>)");
string result = match.Value;
```

Will match all the bold ones, and **.Value** will return whatever is the element's value, in this case ***daniel***, you can also preced the regex with **(i?)** to make it case insensitive to also match the last item in the list

- **<a  href='/profile/daniel'>daniel</a>**
- **<a  href='/profile/danielbc'>daniel</a>**
- <a  href='/profilex/danielbc'>daniel</a>
- **<a  href='/profile/danielbc'>   daniel   </a>**
- <a  href='/profile/danielbc '>daniel</a>
- *<a  href='/PROFILE/danielbc'>   daniel   </a>*

**UPDATE:**

To get the content from any other kind of element, just replace the highlighted section to match the element, (?<=**<a\s*?href='/profile/\w*?'>\s*?**)\w*?(?=**\s*?<\s*?/a\s*?>**).  In your case, `"message-text">hello everyone<wbr/>` would be *(?i)(?<=**"message-text"\s*?>\s*?**)****.*?***(?=**\s*?<\s*?/wbr\s*?>**), and that will get **hello everyone** from the following variations, the **.*?** means match anything (including spaces and punctuations), but as few as possible).  Note that I changed your ending tag from your reply, if it it should be  and not  it's a tiny change you can make to get it working

- "message-text">hello everyone</wbr>
- <wbr asdfjlds "message-text">hello everyone</wbr>
- <wbr "message-text">hello everyone</wbr>

Comment: Jason it worked. And if i want to get the text as i explained above for example hello everyone or any other text that is between "message-text">hello everyone<wbr/> how can i do it ?

Comment: @user1544479 see update, and remember, if you infact have `<wbr/>` as a tag, just swap the position of the **/** in the last part of the regex and you should be in business

Answer (score 1):

Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead of trying to parse manually.

```
var wc = new WebClient();

wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(e.Result);

    var link = doc.DocumentNode
                    .SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='message-profile-name']")
                    .Element("a")
                    .Attributes["href"].Value;
};

wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://chatroll.com/rotternet"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use appropriate tools for spliting symbols array into the meaningful *for you* data array.

You can use a [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to *parse* the string and return the tree of meaningful tokens.

After you can iterate over them and aggregate into the result string based on your own logic.

Comment: I have html agility pack. But i had it also before and tried it alot and didnt understand realy how to extract the text i want.