# How do i get all the text from the string in a loop and not only once?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();

        }
```

Now i have two functions:

```
private void GetProfileNames(string text)
        {
            string startTag = "<a  href='/profile/";
            string endTag = "'>";
            int startTagWidth = startTag.Length;
            int endTagWidth = endTag.Length;
            index = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                index = text.IndexOf(startTag, index);
                if (index == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                // else more to do - index now is positioned at first character of startTag 
                int start = index + startTagWidth;
                index = text.IndexOf(endTag, start + 1);
                if (index == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                // found the endTag 
                profileName = text.Substring(start, index - start);
            }
            return profileName;
        }

        private void GetTextFromProfile(string text)
        {
            string str = "<span class=\"message-text\">";
            string startTag = str;
            string endTag = "<";
            int startTagWidth = startTag.Length;
            int endTagWidth = endTag.Length;
            index = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                index = text.IndexOf(startTag, index);
                if (index == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                // else more to do - index now is positioned at first character of startTag 
                int start = index + startTagWidth;
                index = text.IndexOf(endTag, start + 1);
                if (index == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                // found the endTag 
                profileNameText = text.Substring(start, index - start);
            }

            return profileNameText;
        }
```

Now after the string content line in the DoWork event i called the function: GetProfileNames but when im using a breakpoint on the line: profileNameText = text.Substring(start, index - start); im getting the same profile name all the time i need to close the program run it again.

What i want it to do is when im calling the function in the Dowork event it will make the GetProFileNames function to the end and get all the profile names from the current content that have been downloaded.

---

Somehow i need to call the both functions: GetProfileNames and GetTextFromProfile and i need to create a string of each profile and the text that belong to him.

For example i have this line in the content variable:

```
<span class="message-profile-name" ><a  href='/profile/LipazD'>LipazD</a></span>: <span class="message-text">hello world</span>
```

So I need that the both functions will loop over the content and each time there was itertion i will get a string like string t = "LipazD hello world" 
Next itertion will be: "Daniel how are you ?"

The functions work they get the profile name and the second one get the text but i dont know how ot make itertion loop and to get it all to work.

---

Then when it finish to loop over the content and get all profile names and text for each profile name i need to delete the content and download again a new content and then do it again with the functions finished delete content or just download a new content and so on over and over again.

Comment: I don't understand where your problem comes from, but can't you take a look at the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse HTML?

Comment: As @CodeCaster says: I also recommend using the HTML Agility Pack and combine it with the `WebClient.DownloadString` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx

Comment: I agree with @CodeCaster. Manually parsing HTML/XML is almost never a good idea. There are tons of robust and effective libs for that.

Comment: I dont know how ot use the html aility pack read it some times and i didnt understand how to use it with my code to parse the content and rebuild it back. I didnt understand all the signs and nodes and stuff with the html agility pack.

Comment: It should be easy i guess using the html agility pack.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i extract a text from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892183/how-can-i-extract-a-text-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

doc.Load(wc.DownloadString("http://yourUri.com"));
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//span[@class='message-profile-name'"])
{
    // etc.
}
```

but i think that message-profile-name and message-text are wrapped in a parent element. I recommend looping over that element and then get the child profilename and comment span content

Answer (score 0):

```
var wc = new WebClient();

wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(e.Result);

    var link = doc.DocumentNode
                    .SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='message-profile-name']")
                    .Element("a")
                    .Attributes["href"].Value;
};

wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://chatroll.com/rotternet"));
```